# Woocommerce Rest APi get custom meta field

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to pull a products custom meta and custom taxonomy value from woocommerce using the rest api.  But no matter what I try a can't seem to get it to work.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Example, my products have a custom meta value "product_location".  The post meta value exists and works because I can use this to pull the value into the woocommerce product page:

```
get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'product_location', true );
```

In my functions.php file I've added:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'handle_location' );

function handle_location() {
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'product_location', array(
        'get_callback' => array( $this, 'get_the_product_location' ),
        'schema' => null
    ));        
}   

function get_the_product_location( $post, $field_name, $request ) { 
    return get_post_meta( $post[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}
```

However, when I make a call say https://*******.com/wc-api/v2/products/302341/ the meta data isn't included.  So basically how can I include the additional meta data?  I plan on trying this for a custom taxonomy as well.  Any help is appreciated - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your bottom function to

```
  function get_the_product_location( $post, $field_name, $request ) { 
  return get_post_meta( $post[ 'id' ], 'product_location', $meta_value );
  }
```